# Target IDE disabled when installing JCL/JVCL with Delphi 10.2.3

Tags: delphi, installation, jedi, jvcl

I am going through the process of installing JCL/JVCL on my machine for Delphi (10.2.3). I got the latest Jedi libraries from [GitHub](https://github.com/project-jedi/).

I installed JCL first.

When it asked if I wanted to "install the selected features" and "Do you want to keep JCL expert settings?" I said yes to both.

It finished saying "The installation has finished".

However when I go to install JVCL I can not choose a target IDE because it claims "JCL 2.2 or higher is not installed."

I am running Delphi 10.2.3 and trying install the latest JCL and JVCL from GitHub.

[image: JVCL install page]

Any guidance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Both reasons to close seem bogus.  This is about how to install Delphi and Jedi plugins which are primarily used for programming.  Also, this can definitely be reproduced and is not a typographical error.  I think users may often download the free version of Delphi(the architect version) and try to install it later.  Whether it's helpful in the future to others, time will tell.  Although I did see the problem for others on the internet with no resolution available.

Comment: I appreciate your question and the answer. Same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was my installation of Delphi. I had the trial version which was was the Architect version.

Once I registered with the Professional version with a given serial number I was able to install the JCL and JVCL components.